# Param is missing or the value is empty on POST request to api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api

I've downloaded this repo [(api-presentation)](https://github.com/aomra015/api-presentation) to experiment with api in rails app.

Here's an article with video that explains what is api and how to use it....
http://www.aomran.com/designing--building-restful-json-apis/

Now I'm trying to add a record through POST request with Postman extension and I'm geting:

```
param is missing or the value is empty: contact
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's a screen with the error:

[image]

Comment: Have you tested your api with curl? From your image i see that you chose a `text` instead of `json`.

Comment: I haven't tested it with curl but it should work fine. Still getting the same error after changing text to json.

Comment: anyway your `json` have wrong syntax. I suggest you use curl, it is a not  rails issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added Header/Value and it worked for me. The question's probably lame.

[image]